# Why the float don't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the problem, that the "1"-Form isn't and don't have the width of 100% next to the "Tickets".

Here is a picture what I mean
(The "1" should be the "orange" but it doesn't work) :

[image]

and [here](http://lars-dev.de/dashboard/) is the link how it looks like.

html:

```
<section id="main_content">
            <div class="left inner">            
            <div class="grid_5 left tickets">
                    <div class="header">
                        <i class="icon-pushpin"></i>
                        Neue Tickets
                        <div class="count right"><span>6</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg">
                            <div class="dreieck prio_a"></div>
                            <div class="ava right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" alt="Test"></div>
                            <div class="autor">Lars</div>
                            <small class="subject">Test</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_100 preview">1</div>
            </div>
            <article class="cal right">
                <div class="calender"><?php include('lib/actions/get/calender.php'); ?></div>
            </article>
        </section>
```

custom.css

```
.container_100 { width:100%; min-width:600px; }
.grid_13 { width:13%; min-width:250px; }
.grid_100 { width:100%; }
```

styles.css

```
body { background:#eaedf1; }

a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }

.right { float:right !important; }
.left { float:left !important; }

.hide { display:none !important; }
.show { display:block !important; }

.sep_10 { height:10px; }
.sep_15 { height:15px; }
.sep_20 { height:20px; }
.sep_30 { height:30px; }
.sep_40 { height:40px; }
.sep_50 { height:50px; }
.sep_76 { height:1px; width:76px; float:left; }

#content { width:100%; margin:0; }

nav.tnav { height:51px; width:100%; background:#EB5A47; }
nav .tickets, nav .team, nav .support { margin:10px; height:30px; color:#972216; border:1px solid #972216; width:150px; border-radius:5px; float:left; }
nav div { margin:5px; }

aside { color:#95A1A9; background:#33393D; }
aside a { color:#95A1A9; padding:5px 0; }
aside .nav { padding:5px; height:100%; }
aside .nav ul li { font-size:15px; padding:5px; font-weight:bold; }

.cal { float:left; }
.calender .header { height:51px !important; color:#972216; background:#EB5A47 !important; font-size:24px; line-height:50px !important; vertical-align:middle ; text-align:center; }
.calender table { width:100%; color:#972216; }
.calender i { color:#972216; }
.calender table thead tr th { padding:5px; }
.calender table thead { padding:5px; background:#EB5A47; }
.calender table tbody { padding:5px; background:#EB5A47; }
.calender table tbody tr td { padding:5px; }
.calender table tbody tr td.before { color:#ccc !important; }
.calender table tbody tr td.today { font-weight:bold; }

section .inner { background:#fff; }
article.cal { margin:0 !important; }

.circle img { margin:0; background:transparent; z-index:100; width:35px; height:35px; border-radius:40px; }

#main_content { color:#95A1A9; }
#main_content .grid_5 { margin:0px !important; }
#main_content .header { height:27px; background:#33393D; padding:5px; line-height:28px; vertical-align:center; position:relative; z-index:200; cursor:pointer; }
#main_content i.icon-pushpin { transform:rotate(90deg); }
#main_content .count { width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:50px; background:#EB5A47; color:#972216; position:relative; top:1px; }
#main_content .count span { position:relative; left:4px; bottom:2px; }
#main_content .messages { position:relative; z-index:200; background:#fff; border:1px soild #ccc; cursor:pointer; }
#main_content .messages .msg { color:#33393D !important; border:1px solid #CBCFD6; padding:5px; }
#main_content .messages .msg .autor { color:#33393D !important; }
```

Comment: It's best practice on StacKOverflow to post the code that's causing you trouble (as small a chunk as possible), rather than just linking to your site.  That will make it easier for people to spot problems and will make the question more useful for future readers.

Comment: maybe it's just empty so it doesn't take any space?

Comment: what should that be named in the DOM?

Comment: The class is "grid_100 preview"

Comment: well 100% means the whole size of the parent

Comment: and how I geht the whole size of the empty element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Containing div have `class="left inner"` but it's width is not 100%.
When you set width to 100% it spreads to the containing div's width.

Set the containing div with the desirable width, and it should work.